# $f \in C^2(0,\infty)$ , then how to show that $\Big(\sup_{x>0} |f'(x)|\Big)^2\le 4\big(\sup _{x>0}|f(x)|\big)\big(\sup_{x>0}|f''(x)|\big)$ ?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, inequality, continuity

Let $f \in C^2(0,\infty)$ , then how to show that

$\Big(\sup_{x>0} |f'(x)|\Big)^2\le 4\big(\sup _{x>0}|f(x)|\big)\big(\sup_{x>0}|f''(x)|\big)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $h>0$, Taylor's theorem shows that $$f'(x)=\dfrac{f(x+2h)-f(x)}{2h}-hf''(\xi)$$ for some $\xi\in (x,x+h)$. Hence $|f'(x)|\le hM_2+\frac{M_0}{h}$ where $M_k=\sup \limits_{(0,\infty)}|f^{(k)}|$. Minimize expression $hM_2+\frac{M_0}{h}$ using AM-GM inequality

P.S. It's special case of [Kolmogorov-Landau inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_inequality)

Comment: Nice. (The K-L inequality is given for bounded functions of class two and here it is not necessary, for example with $f(x)= e^x$ , not bounded in the given domain).

Comment: It was very confusing to me how Taylor formula plays a role in this, since it's usually a tool to approximate a smooth function by a polynomial locally. De facto, in order to connect the information of $f,f',f''$, we can consider $\int_a^bf''\phi$ for a test function $\phi$, then integral by part twice.

Comment: @FrankScience, What you mean by test function $\phi$?

Comment: For example, a special choice of $\phi$ leads to the Taylor formula with a remainder of integral form. There are many other choices, and I cannot see any reason why (I mean, the underlying reason) Taylor formula gives the best constant (as claimed in wikipedia). And for related interpolation inequalities, such as Caccioppoli's inequality for Laplacian or general second order elliptic operators, the choice of $\phi$ is usually something related to $f$.

Comment: @FrankScience, thank you for useful information!

Comment: When I was learning first year analysis (approximately a reduced version of Grigorii Fichtenholz's old book *Differential and Integral Calculus*), it gave me an impression that Taylor's formula is the only way to link derivatives. Recently I needed a similar result (I don't need the best constant), I reviewed this and several questions came into my mind without solution. Still, I don't know $L^p$-Gårding's inequality.

Comment: @FrankScience, Dear Frank! I finished university this year and interested in analysis, combinatorics and number theory, but analysis was harder and more interesting to me because i don't know some fundamental terms in deep and I began learning real analysis stubbornly almost 4 month ago from Rudin's book and in my opinion it's really good book with very smart and hard problems which maked my understanding in analysis more better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31918/discussion-between-frank-science-and-rfz).